# Dataframe interval selection performance

Tags: python, performance, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following structure. (system_time is the index)

```
+---------------------+------+------+------+
| System_Time(index)  | var1 | var2 | var3 |
+---------------------+------+------+------+
| 2017-03-28 04:24:00 |    4 |    1 |    2 |
| 2017-03-28 04:32:00 |    5 |    4 |  453 |
| 2017-03-28 04:40:00 |    6 |   21 |    2 |
| 2017-03-28 04:48:00 |    2 |    9 |    5 |
| 2017-03-28 04:56:00 |    5 |    1 |    1 |
| 2017-03-28 05:04:00 |    1 |    2 |    2 |
| 2017-03-28 05:12:00 |    8 |    5 |    2 |
+---------------------+------+------+------+
```

My goal is to loop through a selection of time. Example: I want to get all the rows between: 2017-03-28 04:24:00 and 2017-03-28 04:24:00.

currently I use `dataset.loc[start_date:end_date]` (which does the job.)

Afterwards I increment the time by 8 minutes (start_date and end_date) to get the next selection. (consistent interval of 54 minutes between the start_date and end_date)

With each selection I take the sum, mean or first for each column to get a single row (simple dataframe functions). Afterwards I execute an insert query to store it in a DB.

**the problem:**

There are roughly 15 million records and processing it this way takes about 8 hours.

Any ideas how I could improve the performance?

Comment: Thank you for the acceptance of the answer.
Out of curiosity, could you please post the improved timings on the same dataset? For sure it will be useful for the future reader.

Comment: I cant give a precise indication of the improved timings, since I have also reduced the dataset. But at the moment it takes about an hour to process it, whereof roughly 95% of this time is used to insert the data in the DB. (could be optimized probably). I cant tell you that the time it takes to loop though the selection of data to calculate the mean, max or do X with the data. Takes just a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a [similar problem described](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20521/sliding-window-time-series-data-with-python-pandas-data-frame) at Data Science SO forum.

Going by the suggestions from there (crucially: using [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) function):

```
df["System time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["System time"]) # Convert column type to be datetime
indexed_df = df.set_index(["System time"])           # Create a datetime index
indexed_df = dataset.loc[start_date:end_date]
indexed_df.rolling('480s')                             # Create rolling windows of 8m length
indexed_df.rolling('480s').mean()                      # Then apply functions to rolling windows (here: mean but you can use any lambda as in groupby)
```